# JSON Decoder cannot decode an object into an object

Tags: json, go, struct

```
type MiddleMan struct {
    User CompletedByUser `json:"user"`
}
type CompletedByUser struct {
    DisplayName string `json:"displayName"`
    Id          string `json:"id"`
}
```

Using the following types, I run the code

```
shorterJsonString := `{
    "user":{
        "displayName":null,
        "id":"a03dfee5-a754-4eb9"
    }
 }`

if !json.Valid([]byte(shorterJsonString)) {
    log.Println("Not valid")
}
var middleMan models.MiddleMan

newReader := strings.NewReader(shorterJsonString)
json.NewDecoder(newReader).Decode(&middleMan)

log.Println(middleMan)
```

Unfortunately, the decoder is seemingly broken for nested objects. Rather than spitting out actual objects, the print prints out

```
{{ a03dfee5-a754-4eb9 }}
```

It seems to flatten the whole thing into the id field. What is going on here?

Comment: `middleMan`, which you are printing, is of type `models.MiddleMan`. It has nothing to do with JSON, and thus will receive fmt-style formatting from `log.Println`, which likes to omit field names as well as null fields. You could get it to be slightly more verbose using `log.Printf("%+v\n", middleMan)`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What did you expect to happen / get printed?

The [`log`](https://pkg.go.dev/log) package (which uses the [`fmt`](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt) package) prints structs enclosed in braces, listing field values separated by spaces.

Your `MiddleMan` has a single field, so it'll look like this:

```
{field}
```

Where `field` is another `struct` of type `CompletedByUser`, which has 2 fields, so it'll look like this:

```
{{field1 field2}}
```

Where `field` is of `string` type, being the empty string, so you'll see the value of `field2` prefixed with a space:

```
{{ a03dfee5-a754-4eb9}}
```

If you print it adding field names:

```
log.Printf("%+v", middleMan)
```

You'll see an output like:

```
{User:{DisplayName: Id:a03dfee5-a754-4eb9}}
```

Using another (Go-syntax) format:

```
log.Printf("%#v", middleMan)
```

Output:

```
main.MiddleMan{User:main.CompletedByUser{DisplayName:"", Id:"a03dfee5-a754-4eb9"}}
```

Try this on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/KPxepVOW5EO).

Comment: I expected it to print the whole thing, and not unexpectedly omit most of the object. This seems to me crazy behavior. I would expect a simple Println("smth") to simply print "smth", and not filter it according to its own bias, as it does in most languages.